# Split unsigned char array into array of multiple unsigned char array

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, char

My application is composed of a controller which has several children. The controller use pipe to communicate with is a first child, and child use pipe between us to transfer the question to the next sibling. When a child can process the question, it sends a frame to the controller pipe to make an acquittal.

My problem is because every child could write in the controller pipe, It's possible that the controller read multiple child's frame in the same stream.

So, I want to split this stream to process the child frame individual.

The controller receives only one type of frame:

```
Acquittal Frame
0                 1                 2                 3
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|       CMD       |     NODE ID     |    ERROR FLAG   |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|      DATA LENGTH (optional)       |                 |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+                 |
|   DATA WITH UNDETERMINED SIZE (char *) (optional)   |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|    END FRAME    |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

This frame is compose of multiple information :

- CMD : the acquittal commend that say to controller which question the child respond
- NODE ID : the unique identifier of a child
- Error flag : that can have different value in function of result and commands

The commands :

- A_SET(0xA2) :

  - This command admits only 2 error flag SUCCESS(0x20) and INTERNAL_ERROR(0x50)
  - With this cmd the frame size is 4 no data length and data
- A_DUMP(0xD2) :

  - This command admits only 2 error flag SUCCESS(0x20) and INTERNAL_ERROR(0x50)
  - With this cmd the frame size is 4 no data length and data
- A_LOOKUP(0xB2) :

  - If this command has error flag INTERNAL_ERROR(0x50) or NOT_FOUND(0x44) the frame size will be 4
  - If this command has error flag SUCCESS(0x20) the frame size will be 4 + DATA LENGTH which is encode in two bytes

So in my case for example I want this :

```
{0xd2,0x04,0x20,0x04,0xd2,0x05,0x20,0x04,0xd2,0x06,0x20,0x04,0xd2,0x07,0x20,0x04,0xb2,0x08,0x20,0x01,0x08,0x62,0x6f,0x6e,0x6a,0x6f,0x75,0x72,0x04}
```

And I want to extract an array that look like that :

```
[0] : {0xd2,0x04,0x20,0x04}
[1] : {0xd2,0x05,0x20,0x04}
[2] : {0xd2,0x06,0x20,0x04}
[3] : {0xd2,0x07,0x20,0x04}
[4] : {0xb2,0x08,0x20,0x01,0x08,0x62,0x6f,0x6e,0x6a,0x6f,0x75,0x72,0x04}
```

I have tried multiple thing to do that : with manual array parkour, with `strtok()` function.
So, I show you the last attempt with the stork function here:

```c
enum frameComponents {
    END_FRAME=(unsigned char)0x04,
    ...
}
...

unsigned int getNbFrames(unsigned char * framesStream){
    unsigned int lenFrames = strlen((char * )framesStream);
    unsigned int i,k;
    for(i=0,k=0;i<lenFrames;i++){
        if(framesStream[i]==END_FRAME){
            k++;
        }
    }
    return k;
}


unsigned char ** deserialisation(unsigned char * frameStream){
    //this function return the number of identify frame in the stream
    unsigned int nbFrame = getNbFrames(frameStream);
    unsigned int lenFrames = strlen((char * )frameStream);
    unsigned char **framesArray = malloc(nbFrame * sizeof(unsigned char *));
    unsigned char *tempFrameStream = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*lenFrames+1);
    unsigned char * extractedFrame = (unsigned char *) strtok(tempFrameStream, (char *)END_FRAME);
    strcpy((char *)tempFrameStream,(char *) frameStream);
    int i = 0;
    while(extractedFrame != NULL ) {
        extractedFrame = (unsigned char *) strtok(NULL, (char *)END_FRAME);
        framesArray[i]= malloc(strlen((char *)extractedFrame)+1);
        strcpy((char *)framesArray[i],(char *)extractedFrame);
        i++;
    }
    free(tempFrameStream);
    free(extractedFrame);
    return framesArray;
}
```

But I have multiple problems here

First, `strtok()` doesn't seem to work properly because when I try with one string, I have null return in my array. I don't know if that come from the unsigned int type of my array?

Secondly, when I try to access to frame array outside the function, I have segmentation fault. Even with the malloc() in my array

Comment: `uint8_t *p = original_array, *end = original_array + size_of_original_array; for (unsigned i = 0; p < end; ++i) { memcpy(destination_array[i], p, 4); p += 4; }`? Or something like that.

Comment: I have shown a simple example, but a frame could arrive with an unknown size. For example, I can have this incoming stream : `a2-3-20-4-b2-8-20-1-8-62-6f-6e-6a-6f-75-72-4` so in this case I need return[0] to be `a2-3-20-4` and return[1] to be `b2-8-20-1-8-62-6f-6e-6a-6f-75-72-4`

Comment: `(char *)END_FRAME` is for sure not what you want

Comment: Is `strlen` going to work in this case? It doesn't look like your `char` array is null-terminated.

Comment: To me it's unclear whether this unsigned char arrays or it's strings (aka nul terminated char arrays)

Comment: Can you make a (phony) `main` where you shows how `deserialisation` is called, i.e. how exatcly is the data that `frameStream` points to looking.

Comment: @Chris yes the strlen() work in my case, but I haven't specified a \0 character at the end of a transmission, so it's a bit weird

Comment: How can the caller of `deserialisation` know the number of frames returned?

Comment: @4386427 yes, It's an array of unsigned char because I don't need negative bytes.

Comment: In your example in the comment (`a2-3-20-4-b2-8-20-1-8-62-6f-6e-6a-6f-75-72-4`), why should it be split like `a2-3-20-4` and `b2-8-20-1-8-62-6f-6e-6a-6f-75-72-4`? What's the logic behind that? Is it the `4` that marks the end of each piece? Then you need to use a loop to find that `4` and count the number of bytes to allocate and copy. Other than that the loop in my comment could still be used as a base.

Comment: @MrSolarius So it's not a string.... so applying string functions to the data is wrong but .... then how can you know the number of unsigned char in `frameStream` ? Something is missing here... it's unclear what you are doing. Once again: Please provide a `main` that shows how input data is looking

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes It's a problem because if 4 is found in a model of a frame, that can broke everything. But I have another function that I have not shown here that can decode a frame base of my protocol.`PFrame decodeFrame(unsigned char *frame);` this function return error on global int val if it's not a valide frame

Comment: "Secondly, when I try to access to frame array outside the function, I have segmentation fault" okay... but how do you expects us to help with that when you haven't posted the code?

Comment: @4386427 yes, I have multiple case : A simple acquittal frame can have 4bytes that append only for this type : A_SET = 0xA2, A_DUMP=0xD2. But for a type, A_LOOKUP=0xB2 I don't know the length in advance, I have 2 extra unsigned char that represent length. I have specified my protocol here if you want to check, but it's in french https://github.com/mrsolarius/Process-Dictionary-Project/blob/main/DDP.txt

Comment: @4386427 yes, you right, but finally, I think this is not the main problem in my code.

Comment: @MrSolarius The problem here is that your description in the question is unclear. If you can't explain how the input data look, we simply can't help you decoding it. To me it seems that you are using string functions on an array which isn't a string. That wont work. If you want help, you need to explain what input data are. As I said: Make an example with a (phony) `main` where you construct the input data and then call the function.

Comment: @4386427 you right, and I have updated my question to hopefully increase clarity

Comment: Now your question is better so I removed my close vote. Question: How can `deserialisation` know the total number of unsigned chars in the array? You can't use `strlen` as the input is **not** a string.

Comment: And another question: What shall happen if the "END FRAME" marker isn't present? Example: `0xA2 0x01 0x20 0xab`

Comment: @4386427 you right, this function can't know the size in advance because to know the size, I need to try to decode each possible array. And if an END FRAME marker is not present, and I tried to decode the frame with the function decodeAcquittalFrame() I will place my equivalent of errno to say there is no end flag. Normally, this can't happen because in my child I use a function to end frame that place automatically this flag.

Comment: @MrSolarius Let me put it in another way. The code that reads from the pipe knows exactly how many bytes it has received. For starters you need to pass that information to the decoder. You can't do decoding without that infomation

Comment: Ok, it's because it's not a real string and I can't use strlen()?

Comment: Yes, what you have is a stream of unsigned char. That's not a string and consequently you can't use `strlen`. Therefore you need to get the "stream size" from the function that read from the pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your input data isn't a string but a raw byte stream (aka a stream of unsigned chars), you can't use string functions for the decoder.

You need to implement a parser that takes the protocol into account, i.e. you need to look at each frame and see what command it is. Once you know the command, you can parse the data accordingly.

I will not implement a full parser for you but below is some code that show the principal. The code doesn't put the frames into allocated memory (I'll leave that to you), the code just prints the frame (in 2 out of 3 cases, the last I will leave to you to implement.

```
#define A_SET (0xA2)
#define A_DUMP (0xD2)
#define A_LOOKUP (0xB2)

void deserialisation(unsigned char * frameStream, size_t n)
{
    size_t index = 0;
    while (index < n)
    {
        switch(frameStream[index])
        {
            case A_SET:
                if (index + 4 > n)
                {
                    puts("Too little data! can't continue...");
                    index = n;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Good frame - just print it for now
                    printf("A_SET cmd: ");
                    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf("0x%02X ", frameStream[index + i]);
                    puts("");
                    index += 4;
                }
                break;
                
            case A_DUMP:
                if (index + 4 > n)
                {
                    puts("Too little data! can't continue...");
                    index = n;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Good frame - just print it for now
                    printf("A_DUMP cmd: ");
                    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf("0x%02X ", frameStream[index + i]);
                    puts("");
                    index += 4;
                }
                break;
                
            case A_LOOKUP:
                printf("A_LOOKUP cmd: ");
                // Add code here...
                break;
                
            default:
                puts("Unknow frame! Can't continue...");
                index = n;
                break;
        }
    }
}
    
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char pipeData[] = {0xA2, 0x01, 0x20, 0x04, 0xD2, 0x14, 0x50, 0x04};
    deserialisation(pipeData, sizeof pipeData / sizeof pipeData[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A_SET cmd: 0xA2 0x01 0x20 0x04 
A_DUMP cmd: 0xD2 0x14 0x50 0x04
```